# 502 (Bad Gateway) when trying to access to my Flask api with kubernetes

Tags: flask, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I try to deploy my application on GCP. I have a frontend in Vuejs and an api with Flask and a Postgre database

Everything is deployed in a Kubernetes cluster on GCP.
I can accès to my frontend without any problems, but I cannot access to the api, I have a 502 bad gatteway.
I think a made a mistake in my configuration.
Here is my configuration :

```
**flask-service.yml**

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: flask
  labels:
    service: flask
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: flask
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 5000
    targetPort: 5000
```

vue-service.yml file

```
**vue-service.yml**

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: vue
  labels:
    service: vue
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: vue
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
```

ingress.yml file

```
ingress.yml

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: vue
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /api/*
        backend:
          serviceName: flask
          servicePort: 5000
```

My flask app is deployed with gunicord

```
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 manage:app
```

[image: screeshot of my GCP cluster services]

Do you know where I've made a mistake ? I'm a beginner in kubernetes

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.1-slim

# install netcat
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install netcat && \
    apt-get clean

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add and install requirements
RUN  pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -U gunicorn
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# add entrypoint.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh

# add app
COPY . /usr/src/app

# run server
CMD ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

And my entrypoint.sh

```
echo "Waiting for postgres..."

while ! nc -z postgres 5432; do
  sleep 0.1
done

echo "PostgreSQL started"

gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 manage:app
```

One more edit. In GCP, when I check backend services, there are 3 backends, and one of them doesn't work
But why do I have 3 backend ? I should have juste two no (flask and vue)?

When I check, I have 2 backend services with Flask, and on of them doesn't work

[The backend services (flask) with problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK81L.png)

[the other backend services (flask)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hceMM.png)

My Flask Image logs in GCP show an error. Do you know why ?

[GCP log of my flask image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65p0W.png)

Comment: its not kubernetes issue, its docker container issue ,seems like application server not running in docker, thats why its returning 502, can you share Dockerfile as well ?

Comment: change Type ClusterIP instead of NodePort in service . this should work if am not wrong

Comment: I think your'r right, I made a mistake with que GCP log of my Flask Image. I think there is an error . I add a new screenshoot of my logs

Comment: I tried to change with ClusterIP but I have this error when I try to create ingress : `error while evaluating the ingress spec: service "default/flask" is type "ClusterIP", expected "NodePort" or "LoadBalancer" ` Maybe the solution is in the Flask Image logs (screenshot at the end of my question)

Comment: ClusterIp in service , not ingress , ingress rule seems fine

Comment: Yes it's what I did. In flask-service.yml I replaced type: NodePort by type: ClusterIP.  But it  doesn't work, I have the error above. DO you think that my logs in GCP are OK?

Comment: if you run the Flask service via Docker on your machine, does it respond to requests as expected?

Comment: Yes, on my machine everything is good

Comment: based on logs flask socket running. it ingress + service issue , need to debug at kube level whats going on. Try to send curl request to service IP on kube. if its returning 200 then check ingress rule.

Comment: Can you tell me how to send curl request to service IP on kube ?

Comment: show all your [endpoints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#does-the-service-have-any-endpoints)

Comment: flask ->  10.0.1.6:5000      vue -> 10.0.2.3:8080      postgres -->  10.0.0.10:5432

Comment: Little uptade : I tried to put my Flask pod directly behind a load-balancer and it works. I really dont understand why it doesn't work with my ingress. (my frontend works with my ingress)

Is anyboy here who can help me ? I really don't know what to do

Comment: one more question. on screenshot you have "some backend  services unhealthy" and 0 scheduled pods. What is happening there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I founded the solution. It was a problem with my ingress, I forgot to add an Ingress Controler. (I didn't know anything about Ingress Controler...)

Now I've added an Nginx Ingress Controler and everything works fine !